# Retrieve a key-value pair from a dict as another dict

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
{u'message': u'Approved', u'reference': u'A71E7A739E24', u'success': True}
```

I would like to retrieve the key-value pair for reference, i.e. `{ 'reference' : 'A71E7A739E24' }`.
I'm trying to do this using `iteritems` which does return `k, v` pairs, and then I'm adding them to a new dictionary. But then, the resulting value is `unicode` rather than `str` for some reason and I'm not sure if this is the most straightforward way to do it:

```
ref = {}
for k, v in charge.iteritems():
    if k == 'reference':
        ref['reference'] = v
        print ref
```

{'reference': u'A71E7A739E24'}

Is there a built-in way to do this more easily? Or, at least, to avoid using `iteritems` and simply return:

```
{ 'reference' : 'A71E7A739E24' }
```

Comment: use `dd[k] = v` in your code.

Comment: Ever heard of the primary way to use a hash table which is (in your case) `charge['reference']`?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, yes but I'm trying to return the reference key and its value as a dict. That just fetches the key, that's why I was asking is iteritems the best method to do that?

Comment: Okay... then it's a valid question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to get one key-value pair, it's as simple as

```
ref = { key: d[key] }
```

If there may be multiple pairs that are selected by some condition,

either use `dict` from iterable constructor (the 2nd version is better if your condition depends on values, too):

```
ref = dict(k,d[k] for k in charge if <condition>)
ref = dict(k,v for k,v in charge.iteritems() if <condition>)
```

or (since 2.7) a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (which is syntactic sugar for the above):

```
ref = {k,d[k] for k in charge if <condition>}
<same as above>
```

Comment: Thank you, that achieves what I was trying to do and was very clear!

Comment: Btw, your value is `unicode` rather than `str` because it's `unicode` in the original dict, too.

Comment: That makes sense, and turns out it doesn't matter that it stays in unicode for what I'm doing. Thanks again Ivan.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with using iteritems is that you increase lookup time to O(n) where n is dictionary size, because you are no longer using a hash table

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand the question:
is this what you are trying to do:
    `ref={'reference',charge["reference"]}`

Comment: I had a a couple typos I fixed. Basically just trying to do return { 'reference' : 'A71E7A739E24' } from that larger dict, however possible. Seems like I'm not doing it the most straight forward way by using iteritems.

Comment: ah I see, that does do what I'm trying to do but couldn't really understand it at first. thank you.